# PDO prepared statement with variable SELECT

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

my question is simple - I want to have variable SELECT but this doesnt work, probably because of param type casting. How can I make it work?

```
$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT :select FROM hp_data");
$statement->bindValue(":select", $_GET['polozky']);
$statement->execute();
$rows = $statement->fetchAll();
```

Or is it safe to simply put SELECT into query? I guess it is not.

```
$pdo->prepare("SELECT {$_GET['polozky']} FROM hp_data")
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, it's not safe to do this. You will need to handle your own validation. And even then, I would advise against this as any bugs in your validation algorithm become a full SQL injection exploit.

Comment: **Table and Column names cannot be replaced by parameters in PDO.**

Comment: Please see http://us3.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php#69304